# Can't See Staged and Unstaged Files List in Git Gui

Tags: git, git-gui

My Git Gui is no longer functioning properly - I cannot see the "Staged" and "Unstaged" files list in my GUI (so I cannot switch between individual files).

I'm fairly certain this is a glitch, but I don't know how to restore the default setting for the program so that I can see these.

I am using Windows 10.  Up to now, it worked fine - and then somehow the program became minimized in a way I couldn't restore.  I used "CTRL+Space" to bring up the windows menu for the program and "Maximized" the program, so it was visible - then dragged the window size to a more manageable size (so it didn't fill the screen).  This process somehow removed the file lists (normally on the left-hand size of the program).

Re-maximizing or minimizing the program doesn't bring the lists back.  Nor does closing the program and re-opening it.

A picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

EDIT:  I've uninstalled git and re-installed the latest versino (2.19.1.windows.1), with no change in my problem.

Git-Gui version is 0.21.GITGUI

Comment: Does the command line show anything?

Comment: You mean when I open Git Bash?  That seems to function normally.  And I know that the Git Gui is correctly loading the source directory and information, because hitting "Amend Last Commit" radio button shows me the previous commit message.

Answer (score 3):

(1) hover your mouse over left side of the window, there should be a draggable splitter

(2) close git gui, run `git config --edit`, find there lines:

```
[gui]
      ....
      geometry = 795x308+182+182 1 193
```

replace the 1 with some 100, start it back

Comment: Just removing the whole `geometry = ...` line also solves the issue, and on the next start `git gui` uses a default setting.